# Getting 404 Not Found while setuping http-proxy-middleware

Tags: javascript, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I did http-proxy-middleware setup in my node js app.

If I called "http://localhost:4000/test" then I am getting my JSON output
but if I called "https://csv.empyra.com/app1/test" then I am getting 404 error
Kindly check my code if I am doing something wrong here. please check my screenshot also here.

```
reverse_proxy node app Config.json  {
"routes": [{
        "route": "/app1",
        "address": "http://localhost:4000"
    },
    {
        "route": "/app2",
        "address": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
]}
```

app

[Success when getting JOSN with Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2EuD.png)

[Errorwhen not getting JOSN with my host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68dDF.png)

Comment: "Kindly check my code" = where's your code? It should be in your question.

Comment: sure i am adding code

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane I added JSON config and screenshot for error let me know if I am missing something

Comment: I do not understand the role of "https://csv.empyra.com/app1/test" in relation to your project.

Comment: I am doing reverse proxy with host "https://csv.empyra.com" and in my config JSON file I mapped my localhost:4000 with "https://csv.empyra.com/app1"